# Add Emptyvalue property to Query param to generate open api yaml

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I am using swashbuckle to generate openapi yaml configuration.
I have this url. `http://localhost.com/api/comics?limit=100&likedByPeople`.
Here I am using `likedByPeople` as EmptyValue Query Parameter. I need to generate yaml as below

```
parameters:
    - in: query
      name: likedByPeople
      schema:
        type: boolean
      allowEmptyValue: true
```

I searched on it but couldn't figure out the way. `SwaggerParameter` and `SwaggerSchema` both do not have `allowEmptyValue` property. But I see that in `Microsoft.OpenApi.Models`. I am not sure how to proceed on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by extending `System.Attribute` and implemented a corresponding filter extending `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.IParameterFilter`. Then registered it startup configureServices.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen( c => {
c.ParameterFilter<SwaggerParamInfoFilter>();
})
```

Reference from the examples of [AnnotationsParameterFilter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/AnnotationsParameterFilter.cs) and [SwaggerParameterInfo](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/SwaggerParameterAttribute.cs)